# SCP help -- downloading files/folder from a blocked up

Tags: grid, scp

We have couple of Grid Servers from MediaTemple and one of the servers IP address has been banned/blocked and cant be accessed from our country. We contacted MediaTemple for a solution but they didnt really help much so now we need tro retrieve some files from that server..

I figured out a way to access the files via SCP but i think my command is wrong..

What im trying to do: 
Connect to (server B) and download files from (server A : Sever with banned IP)

I can connect to SERVER A with the following SSH Command :

*scp [server info]:[File Location] /*

but when i try it comes up with the msg  Read-only file system..

is there any easy process to do this? or a different command?

Answer (score 0):

Login to the servrr using `ssh server ip`, go to the required location where the files are present, change the file permissions using `chmod` command and try copying again

Comment: thanks for the info.. i just tried that but still the same error